# Object level locking in c++

Tags: c++, locking

Suppose I have two classes, P and S. Each of the objects of class P has a reference to an object of class S. Suppose there are a total 20 objects of class P, 10 of those have object S1 and the other 10 have object S2, where S1 and S2 are objects of class S. Is it possible to lock S1 and S2 separately such that two objects having S1 and S2 respectively can run in parallel?

Comment: Indeed. The simplest idea would be to put a mutex in `S` and use that for synchronization.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question. Depending on details you might either need no locking at all or it might be that what you want is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::mutex`.

```
class S
{
 std::mutex mutex;
 ...
};
```

This way, all references to S1 will be locked when S1.mutex is locked, and all references to S2 will be locked when S2.mutex is locked. This way they are locked independently. If you instead declare the `mutex` as `static`, it will give you the undesired effect, hope that clarifies the difference.